# E: Package 'clamav' has no installation candidate?

Tags: kali-linux, gnome-terminal, bugs, clamav

I am trying to install clamav in kali for removal of viruses in PC and USB.and I did:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install clamav
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package clamav is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'clamav' has no installation candidate
```

Any Help??

Comment: Have you run apt-get  update before that?

Comment: yes, i have tried it again after reading ur comment @Svetlin_Tonchev

Comment: I have no problem installing the package. Maybe problem in sources.lists?

Comment: Check my another [thread ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245088/how-to-open-leafpad-as-root-in-gnome-terminal-in-kali-linux?noredirect=1#comment420974_245088)regarding the problem of this installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your repos:
http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Update the local cache using:
`apt-get update` (as Svetlin Tonchev said.)

try again with:
`apt-get install clamav`

Optional:
Search for it using:
`apt-cache search clamav`

Comment: I noticed that usually on debian based you need to also explicitly install freshclam package, which is the tool that updates the virus database. So the command would become `apt-get install clamav clamav-freshclam`, because it does not automatically propose it

Comment: Thanks! I remember. I installed it once over a year ago. there i had to install freshclam too.

Comment: What is installation candidate for installing ClamAV @lese

Comment: I don't remember honestly, I just remember each time I installed clamav on Debian based freshclam was missing

Comment: @Aevo did you check you have the required repository configured in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as Spanguel suggested? and if you do, did you `apt-get update` before retry to install `clamav clamav-freshclam` ?

Answer (score 1):

Official guide from clamav site:

ClamAV can be found in the apt repository. Run this command to install ClamAV:

```
apt-get install clamav
```

If you need clamd, you may also want to run:

```
apt-get install clamav-daemon
```

For the stable release, the packages are updated via the StableUpdates mechanism.

If you require support for scanning compressed RAR files you first need to enable the non-free archive and then you can install the RAR-plugin using:

```
apt-get install libclamunrar6
```

To test the installation, you can try to scan the test files in the `clamav-testfiles` package.

The package maintainers can be reached at `clamav-devel` at `lists.alith.debian.org`. More info at [tracker.debian.org/pkg/clamav](http://tracker.debian.org/pkg/clamav).