# How to open Leafpad as root in gnome-terminal in kali linux?

Tags: root, kali-linux, gnome-terminal

I am following [this](http://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?2510-Dependencies-hell-!!!) in which there is some commands:

```
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main
## Security updates
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

to be written in leafpad to install clamav and other softwares. 
but I want to know how to open leafpad as root in terminal writing above commands and saving it.  Any Help?
Sory for the bad English.

I am trying to install clamAV using commands still there is problem.

Comment: please don't add answers if this not effectively answer the question. Instead edit your question. Anyway, you decided what repository to add. If this repos contain the package(s) you are looking for, then it will probably work. just do it and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

leafpad is just a text editor and you are not obliged to use it only because they describe it in the forum. Which text editor to use is your choice. Anyway do it as follow

```
sudo leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list
```

fix your sources list in order to add the repositories **you repute** necessary, and remember to update your local package index with the latest changes made in the repositories (since you are going to add new ones) with the following command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install clamav clamav-freshclam
```